# Time out issue while sending MAKE_CREDENTIAL(0x01) response

Tags: android, android-authenticator, fido-u2f, webauthn, fido

I am developing Android Authenticator. I am getting the following exception while sending MAKE_CREDENTIAL response. I got this issue while debugging with webauthn.io site. Also tried with https://webauthn.me/debugger#

**The operation either timed out or was not allowed. See: https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#sec-assertion-privacy.**

But I am using `Timer` and `TimerTask` to send **kKeepAliveMillis** for every 500 milliseconds after receiving MAKE_CREDENTIAL request. I don’t know why I am getting is this issue. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: First of all, you don't need to send kKeepAliveMillis for every 500 miliseconds at all. It still works. Next, you show your MakeCred response in hex here.

Comment: @BaoHoa previously I added the response with some issues. Now I fixed that issue. Please look into that issue. Response Link : https://pastebin.com/kapXL0Na